# ruby /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- libnotify (LoadError)

Tags: ruby

I am ruby fresher,  I want to use this pomo util: https://github.com/visionmedia/pomo#readme.

But when I excute pomo on my ubuntu 12.10 terminal:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:365:in 
  `block in require_program': 
   program version required (Commander::Runner::CommandError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:364:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:364:in `require_program'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:52:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/delegates.rb:11:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': 
      cannot load such file -- libnotify (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pomo-2.0.2/lib/pomo.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pomo-2.0.2/bin/pomo:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pomo:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pomo:23:in `<main>'
```

How can I do .thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not completely sure what the problem is. But at least start by fixing this error:

```
cannot load such file -- libnotify
```

...with:

```
sudo apt-get install libnotify1
sudo gem install libnotify
```

With good luck it will fix the issue.

Comment: maybe the code `spec.add_dependency('libnotify', '~> 0.8') if Pomo::OS.linux?` not works

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was an RVM Ruby version issue. I was using Ruby 1.9 and when I changed it to 1.8, the migration worked.

```
rvm use 1.8
```